# Disable refresh on changing Tabs from the action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) to create an app with four tabs in the action bar [tab1][tab2][tab3][tab4].

When I change from a tab to the nearest one, the destination tab doesn t refresh for example from 1->2 , 3->4 or 3->2, but the problem is when I change from 1->3 or 4, 2->4 ...(a far tab) the destination tab refresh, how can I disable this ?

Comment: it s the same code as the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial code, a new instance of fragment is getting generated every time it went to background.

```
switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }
```

Instead of it create fragment at the top level i,e create once you start the class.

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
TopRatedFragment frag1;
GamesFragment frag2;
MoviesFragment frag3;
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            if(frag1 == null)
            frag1 = new TopRatedFragment(); 
            return frag1;
        case 1:
            //repeat same here
        case 2:
            //repeat same here
        }
```

By this, if an instance of fragment already exist, then it will return that instance instead of new one.